# php- processing two related forms on same page

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

I'm new to php and have read lots of posts here in SO but couldn't find an answer for my specific question.

I have a database in which I store information about projects (project name, start date, status, etc...). I'm trying to create an updating api, so the user can update the project info.

What I would like to do is to let the user choose a project from a regular html "select". Once the user chose the project I would like to display a new form containing all the fields that the user can update. The issue is that I would like to have all the project current information (before the update) as values of the form. (So I must send the user selected project name and get back all the info in order to display it on the second form).
For example: let's say that there are 2 possible project statuses: "on execution" and "frozen", then I would like to put as "selected" the current status, and let the user change it if he wants to and then send the second form so I can update the db info.

I would like to know what is the best way to implement that. Solutions can contain javascript if needed.

Thank you in advance for your time and pacience.

Comment: Do you have any code that you can show for us?

Comment: no, sorry about that.